# map don't display with googlemaps js API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I'm tryin to use a sample code in order to have a webpage in order to display multiples pushpin on the map.

Here is my html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps</title>
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAs4c8xnkxcZNRK6yQt-Y21N1L3mT1AFfE&callback=initMap">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map" style="width: 1024px; height: 768px"></div>

<noscript><b>JavaScript must be enabled in order for you to use Google Maps.</b> 
  However, it seems JavaScript is either disabled or not supported by your browser. 
  To view Google Maps, enable JavaScript by changing your browser options, and then 
  try again.
</noscript>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

     // A function to create the marker and set up the event window
function createMarker(point,name)
{
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, title: name});
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(name);});

    return marker;
}

function initMap() 
{

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));//, { center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},zoom: 8});

    var optionsCarte =  {
                            zoom: 8,
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.5, 2.9),
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                        };


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), optionsCarte);

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // ========== Read paramaters that have been passed in ==========

    // If there are any parameters at the end of the URL, they will be in  location.search
    // looking something like  "?q=My+First+Point@59.591,17.82"

    // skip the first character, we are not interested in the "?"
    var query = location.search.substring(1);

    // split the rest at each "&" character to give a list of  "argname=value"  pairs
    var pairs = query.split("&");

    for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) 
    {
        // break each pair at the first "=" to obtain the argname and value
        var pos = pairs[i].indexOf("=");
        var argname = pairs[i].substring(0,pos).toLowerCase();
        var value = pairs[i].substring(pos+1);

        // process each possible argname  -  use unescape() if theres any chance of spaces
        if (argname == "q") 
        {
            var text = unescape(value);
            var parts = text.split("@");
            var latlng = parts[1].split(",");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latlng[0]),parseFloat(latlng[1]));
            var title = parts[0];
            var marker = createMarker(point,title);       
            marker.setMap(map);       
            bounds.extend(point);
        }
    }

    //map.setZoom(map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
    map.fitBounds(bounds)
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());

}   

</script>
```

The trick is to use the url with parameters in order to add locations to display :

Ex: http://myserver.com?q=MyFirstPoint@59.591,17.82

Actually nothing is displayed..

Anyone can help me please ? My API key is on the code ;)

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

Fab'

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> ?q=MyFirstPoint@59.591,17.82&q=MyLastPoint@54.591,12.82

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map" style="width: 550px; height: 450px"></div>


<script>
    (function (myGoogleMap) {
        var map;
        var latLngBounds;

        myGoogleMap.init = function () {
            console.log('init');
            latLngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {
                    lat: -34.397,
                    lng: 150.644
                },
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
                panControl: false,
                zoomControl: true,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                scaleControl: false,
                streetViewControl: false,
                overviewMapControl: false
            });
            getData();
        };

        function getData() {


            var query = location.search.substring(1);

            // split the rest at each "&" character to give a list of  "argname=value"  pairs
            var pairs = query.split("&");

            for (var i = 0, l = pairs.length; i < l; i++) {
                // break each pair at the first "=" to obtain the argname and value
                var pos = pairs[i].indexOf("=");
                var argname = pairs[i].substring(0, pos).toLowerCase();
                var value = pairs[i].substring(pos + 1);

                // process each possible argname  -  use unescape() if theres any chance of spaces
                if (argname == "q") {
                    var text = decodeURI(value);
                    var parts = text.split("@");
                    var latlng = parts[1].split(",");
                    setMarker(parseFloat(latlng[0]), parseFloat(latlng[1]), parts[0]);
                }
            }
            centerMap();
        }

        function setMarker(lat, lng, contentString) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            latLngBounds.extend(latLng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map
            });
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
            });
            marker.addListener('click', function () {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }

        function centerMap() {
            map.fitBounds(latLngBounds);
        }

    }(window.myGoogleMap = {}))
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAs4c8xnkxcZNRK6yQt-Y21N1L3mT1AFfE&callback=myGoogleMap.init"></script>

<noscript><b>JavaScript must be enabled in order for you to use Google Maps.</b>
    However, it seems JavaScript is either disabled or not supported by your browser.
    To view Google Maps, enable JavaScript by changing your browser options, and then
    try again.
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this could help.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain me please, why my pushpin is not visible, according to my code ? thanks :)

Comment: new google.maps.Marker() expect an object with the propetys "position" and "title" but you put the position as an own parameter.

Comment: *expected *properties

Comment: var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, title: name});

Answer (score 2):

You have a

```
 callback=initMap
```

but I see no function by this name

and similar you have

```
<body onunload="GUnload()">
```

but I see no function by this name

You must be suure you call the proper  init function for display the maps and check in browser console for other errors

Comment: Hello, i added an InitMap() function, so my map is dispayed but just the "InitMap" function is called...not the rest of the code :(

Comment: Hi @WalterFabioSimoni in initMap you should perform the correct call for the rest of your code .. (i haven't evaluate your goal but only your question ..)

Comment: Hey thanks, i ported the code to v3 (first post edited), my map display. I added a point but no pushpin visible :( Any idea ?

Comment: I have tested you code and in console show an map.getBoundsZoomLevel is not a function ( i don't know if you have this function somewhere ..) commentin this the marker not show because the condition you setted don't match .. try .. evaluating the for and the  if before the marker draw .. I can't do more of this ..

Comment: Yeah, getBoundsZoomLevel didn't exist on v3, i replaced by the good. I tested the For-If, and i really enter on the createMarker() :s

Comment: Well i have looked at you code with firebugs (you can do it too) and the program flow don't enter in the for loop because you var query is empty try check your code for this  .. if think my suggestion are been useful and i think i have answer at you question  ..

Comment: Hmm strange, i add a simple window.alert and it display it

Comment: I don't add an alert i have only tested via debugger you code with breakpoint and there aren't the condition for show the marker ..

Comment: I use the debugger to, and i enter in the CreateMarkerFonction(). For information, i use this address : file:///E:/Users/XXXX/Documents/MutliMaps.html?q=My+First+Point@59.591,17.82

Comment: Solved, i edit my code ! It was an error on the google.maps.marker().

Comment: welll . 
I hope my answer will be helpful